# Namespace set as Used because of One Type Inside being Used?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I just noticed this. I don't know why this is the case, if i use one element from a namespace i don't want anything else to be accessible without having to use the namespace. For example here, this code is valid:

```
namespace Test
{
    struct Magic
    {
        int poof;
    };

    struct Magic2
    {
        int poof;
    };

    int Alakazam(const Magic& m)
    {
        return m.poof;
    }

    int Alakazam(const Magic2& m)
    {
        return m.poof;
    }
};

using Magic = Test::Magic;

int main()
{

    Alakazam(Magic());        // valid
    Alakazam(Test::Magic2()); // valid

    Test::Alakazam(Magic()); // what i want to only be valid
    Test::Alakazam(Test::Magic2()); // this too
}
```

Any reasoning behind this? Does the spec state that this has to be true?

Comment: This is called *argument-dependent lookup*.

Comment: Is `poof` a very good idea for a PC variable name?http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Poof

Comment: @EdHeal - it has other meanings, as well, particularly in the context of magic.

Comment: @EdHeal There's nothing wrong with gay or transgender variables.

Comment: Why don't you just add `using Test::Magic;` in a minimal scope? It's the same thing, but looks a little less funny. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by immbis in the comment, this is defined by the standard:

> **3.4.2: Argument dependent name lookup**
>
> 1. When the postfix-expression in a function call is an unqualified-id, other namespaces not considered during the usual
>      unqualified lookup may be searched, and in those namespaces,
>      namespace-scope friend function or function template declarations not
>      otherwise visible may be found. These modifications to the search
>      depend on the types of the arguments (and for template template
>      arguments, the namespace of the template argument).
>
>    ...

If you want to defeat this mecanism, you have to use nested namespace like this, but it's tricky:

```
namespace Test
{
    struct Magic
    {
        int poof;
    };
    struct Magic2
    {
        int poof;
    };

    namespace Test2 {   // use a nested namespace that will not be searched autoamtically 
        int Alakazam(const Magic& m)
        {
            return m.poof;
        }

        int Alakazam(const Magic2& m)
        {
            return m.poof;
        }
    } 
    using namespace Test2;  // but give some access to the enclosing namespace 
};
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/KzYioP) :  Then, your two first calls will not be valid any longer.  However, the last call in your example is still possible:  you can't prevent the use of fully qualified names outside of the namespace.